# Fedora 22 - unable adjust screen brightness

Tags: fedora, monitor, gnome, brightness, gnome-3

My laptops is MSI GE60 2QD apache, i use dual boot to install Fedora 22 beta and `yum upgrade` already, but i still can't adjust my screen brightness. I have no problem to adjust brightness on Window 8.

Following is the output of xrandr:

```
[kelvin@apache ~]$ xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x181) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
        Identifier: 0x180
        Timestamp:  88929
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Clones:    
        CRTC:       0
        CRTCs:      0
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
  1920x1080 (0x181) 159.667MHz *current
        h: width  1920 start    0 end    0 total 1920 skew    0 clock  83.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start    0 end    0 total 1080           clock  77.00Hz
[kelvin@apache ~]$
```

No difference even if i use xbacklight to set different value:

```
[kelvin@apache ~]$ xbacklight -set 10
[kelvin@apache ~]$ xbacklight -set 0
[kelvin@apache ~]$ xbacklight -set 100
[kelvin@apache ~]$
```

I tried xrandr but i can't set output because i can't even get the name from `xrandr` output above:

```
[kelvin@apache ~]$ xrandr --brightness 0.7
xrandr: --brightness must be used after --output
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
```

[kelvin@apache ~]$

This is the screenshot of my gnome panel(my laptop not support wayland):
http://i58.tinypic.com/av6gyu.png (i don't have enough reputation to upload image)

As you can see, there's only volume control but no brightness control.

Any help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use:

```
xrandr --listactivemonitors
```

to see your active monitor(s) 
this is my case:

```
Monitors: 3
 0: +*eDP1 1366/340x768/190+0+0  eDP1
 1: +DP1 1920/520x1080/290+1366+0  DP1
 2: +HDMI1 1920/520x1080/290+3286+0  HDMI1
```

after that you need to use:

```
xrandr --output <monitor> --brightness <value>
```

for change screen brightness.